# BASH: How to split a string after a specified character + 2 characters?

Tags: bash

I have a string in bash, which is the following:

```
123.123123
123.1
123
```

I want this result:

```
123.12
123.1
123
```

So how can I trim each line to a specified character + at most 2 additional characters?

Comment: Specified what character ? `grep -o ".*\..."` ?

Comment: Which character have you specified?

Comment: @TomFenech Judging by the input and output i would assume the `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

string="1234.12345"

pos=`expr index $string .`
echo $pos
substring= expr substr $string 1 $((pos+2))
echo $substring
```

This way you will obtain a position of point `.` with `expr index $string` and than you get substring with `expr substr $string 1 $((pos+2))` (substring from char 1 to char $pos + 2).

Useful link: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

EDIT:
Probably using regex as @Martin Valgur proposed is much shorter:

```
string="1234.12345"
substring= expr "$string" : '\(.*[.]..\)'
echo $substring
```

Answer (score 1):

For your updated requirements you could use this sed

```
sed 's/\(\.[^ ]\?[^ ]\?\)[^ ]*/\1/g'
```

#### Example

```
echo 123.123123 123.1 123 | sed 's/\(\.[^ ]\?[^ ]\?\)[^ ]*/\1/g'

123.12 123.1 123
```

Comment: This doesn't work for `echo 123.123123 | sed 's/\(\.[^ ]\?[^ ]\?\)[^ ]*/\1/g'`

Comment: @Ian2thedv Yes it does...

Comment: You're right, I thought it should produce `123.123 123`, my bad! Upvoting when I can :)

Comment: @Ian2thedv What do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex functionality of `expr` for this:

```
expr "$string" : '\(.*[.]..\)'
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question. I have numbers in the string which are integers, and number with only one digit after the point.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, use *string indexes*. You can split the string int which every characters you want. Simply pick the indexes you want to capture. For example:

```
myvar=123.123123 123.1 123
echo ${myvar:0:6}    # 123.12
echo ${myvar:11:5}   # 123.1
echo ${myvar:17:3}   # 123
```

Which you can easily put together as:

```
echo "${myvar:0:6} echo ${myvar:11:5} echo ${myvar:17:3}"
# result: 123.12 123.1 123
```

or from the end of the string:

```
echo ${myvar: -3}    # 123
```

**Note:** to index from the *end* of the string you either leave a space before the negative number or put it in parens (e.g. `${myvar: -2}` = `23`, or `${myvar:(-3)}` = `123`)

Comment: If you are going to downvote, please have the integrity to point out what you think is wrong with the post?

Comment: My guess would be that it uses hard-coded lengths and doesn't allow you to specify a character.

Comment: Originally the question was just how do I split this string like this..... I see now he wants an algorithm, not just how do I split it `:)`